# Build Failed when compiling card.io, how can I fix it to make it work?

Tags: xcode5, ios7.1, card.io

Errors:
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_CMGetAttachment", referenced from:
      -[CardIOVideoStream captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:] in libCardIO.a(libCardIO.a-arm64-master.o)
  "_CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer", referenced from:
      -[CardIOVideoFrame process] in libCardIO.a(libCardIO.a-arm64-master.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Answer (score 0):

Dave from card.io here.

@user3512652 did you follow [these integration instructions](https://github.com/card-io/card.io-iOS-SDK#setup)?

> if you are using Xcode 5 or newer:
>     * Add only this single framework to your project: AVFoundation (as an `Optional` [i.e., weak-linked] library)
>     * and confirm that these two Build Settings are both enabled:
>       * `Enable Modules (C and Objective-C)`
>       * `Link Frameworks Automatically`